# Multiple columns in UITableView

Tags: iphone

i am developing a biblkereder application n iPhone/ipad i have done the iPhone application successfully,but in iPad i need a multiple coloum view to display the verses.i am using tableview to display the verses.if the chapter contain 50 verses it need to display in two colums twenty-five twetyfive.i had search lot in google for this implkemntaion but i didn't get the correct tutorial

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        return [delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish count];
    }
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    readCell *cell = (readCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier

                 ] autorelease];
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"readCell" owner:self options:nil]; 
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0]; 


        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:18.0];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

        table.opaque = YES;
        table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        table.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.chapterAndVerse.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row+1];
        cell.chapterAndVerse.frame=CGRectMake(0, 10, 20.0, 20.0);
        cell.textLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@",[delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:18.0];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

this the code for diaplying verses according to chapter in iPhone.but i need a splitvew like the magazine apps in iPad.`chapteranderse` is the label.`delegate.allSelectedVerseEnglish` is they away which contains verses.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

why not use two table views?

Here is my idea.. add two table views on screen.. give them sperate tags and on the touch of a first table's cell reload the second table..

Comment: yea u said the right thing.but the problem is how can we split the the string into two tableiews???